# Position of Z-axis label in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

- I am drawing a 3D Gnuplot graph with the following script.
- My Gnuplot version is `gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3`.
- My problem is that with the default position of the Z-axis label, it's always getting cut (being placed outside the boundary). I would like to know the command to place X/Y/Z axis label at the coordinate on the graph as I prefer.

```
    set pm3d 
    set grid 
    set palette defined (-1 "blue", 0 "white", 1 "red")
    set notitle

    set ztics 0.10
    set xlabel "Label 1"
    set ylabel "Label 2"
    set zlabel "Label 3"

    splot "data" using ($1/$2):3:($4+$5) with pm3d notitle pause -1

    set term post enhanced color "Serif" 20
    set output "graph.eps"
    replot
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to tweak the `{offset <offset>}` option, for example:

```
set xlabel "Label 1" offset 1,1,1
```

which moves the xlabel approximately 1 character in each of the x, y and z axes relative to its original position.

As per the help page, you can specify one of `first`, `second`, `graph`, `screen` or `character` (this is the default) for the coordinate system to be used for the offset:

```
set xlabel "Label 1" offset graph 1,1,1
```

Comment: thanks. It works. It was surprising that with an older version of Gnuplot, I didn't actually need the 'offset' keyword.